# iOS: How to maintain separator while using componentSeparatedByCharactersInSet

Tags: ios, nsstring, token, tokenize

I have a String like $29@@rent1@@rent2@@rent3$. Now I did something as below:

```
NSString* input = @"$29@@rent1@@rent2@@rent3$";
NSString* token = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"$"];
NSArray* values = [input componentSeparatedByCharactersInSet:token];

for(NSString* val in values)
{
    NSLog(@"Result = %@",val);
}
```

This results into below:

```
Result : 
Result : 29@@rent1@@rent2@@rent3
Result :
```

Now, Here what I want is, to receive result like below:

```
Result : $t3$29@@rent1@@rent2@@ren
```

The point is I want to maintain the separator. any help on this?

Comment: What is your question, exactly?

Comment: not getting actually question what is this. i am surprised how did they get +1 :) please explain who given + vote what did you understand with this question.

Comment: I want result string with components. `componentSeparatedByCharactersInSer` will return array of string which does not include separator characters. I want string with separator.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt if i understood your question clearly. `componentSeparatedByCharactersInSet` will divide the string based on the separating character. The separated string will not contain separating character, if you want to put it back you can simply append it to the separated string something like

```
 for(NSString* val in values)
    {
        NSString *appendedString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%@$",val]; //appending the separator to both sides
        NSLog(@"Result = %@",appendedString);
    }
```

Comment: this will work only If I am separating with `$` only. What if I want to separate with `$@` both?